# How to find actual location of library used by linker (gcc)

Tags: gcc, gnu-make

I have this compile command

```
qcc -Vgcc_ntoarmv7le -lang-c++ -Wl,-rpath-link,\
C:\Users\mureadr\Desktop\A\QNX_SDK\target\qnx6/armle-v7/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,\
C:\Users\mureadr\Desktop\A\QNX_SDK\target\qnx6/armle-v7/usr/lib -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-rpath,\
C:/fs/mp/qt5/lib -Wl,-rpath,C:/fs/mp/fordhmi/lib -shared -Wl,-soname,libHmiLogging.so.1\
-o libHmiLogging.so.1.0.0 .obj/hmiloggingcategory.o .obj/hmiloggingcategoryregistry.o\
.obj/hmiperformancelogging.o .obj/hmitracelogging.o\
-LC:\Users\mureadr\Desktop\A\QNX_SDK\target\qnx6/armle-v7/lib \
-LC:\Users\mureadr\Desktop\A\QNX_SDK\target\qnx6/armle-v7/usr/lib \
-LC:/Users/mureadr/Desktop/A/HMI_FORGF/qt5binaries/lib -lQt5Core \
-LC:/QNX650/target/qnx6/armle-v7/lib -LC:/QNX650/target/qnx6/armle-v7/usr/lib -lm
```

When I run it under `make`, it runs fine but using another build system, I get the error

```
C:\Users\mureadr\Desktop\A\QNX_SDK\host\win32\x86\usr\bin\ntoarm-ld: cannot find -lQt5Core
cc: C:/Users/mureadr/Desktop/A/QNX_SDK/host/win32/x86/usr/bin/ntoarm-ld caught signal 1
```

Obviously the other build system doesn't have access to all the included directories.

**Question**

How can I find out which directory `Qt5Core` was pulled from?

Is there a linker option that will make it say `I got Qt5Core from directory X`?

I ran `make` with `--debug=a` but I didn't get any info about `Qt5Core`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a linker option that will make it say I got Qt5Core from directory X?

Yes. It is `-trace`. To pass it via `gcc`, use `gcc ... -Wl,-trace...`.

This will cause the linker to print the name of each input (object file or library) that
it receives from the commandline together with the absolute path where it located
the same.

BTW, passing debug options to `make` will produce debugging info from `make`
but none from tools that are invoked by `make`.